# Loading Baqend References

Tags: baqend

Is there a way to load a referenced object with having to strip out the class name?

So for example, in my app I frequently load data from referenced classes.

So I have a data object with a reference to this: /db/Shifts/73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6

```
return db.Shifts.load('73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6')
```

is what is needed to load the reference, so I have a lot of this going on:

```
var cleanID = obj.ShiftID.replace('/db/Shifts/','');
return db.Shifts.load(cleanID)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Like this?

```
return db.load('/db/Shifts/73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways how your problem can be solved.

You can load an object by id (`/db/Shifts/73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-
10c4121b3fc6`) or by a key (`73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6`) both is 
supported by the load method.

```
// resolves both to the same object
db.Shifts.load('/db/Shifts/73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6')
db.Shifts.load('73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6')
```

You can access the id or the key directly from any object reference by using the corresponding accessors:

For instance, you have an object `obj` which have a reference `shift` to a Shifts instance. Then you can easily access the id or key of the reference directly.

```
obj.shift.id == '/db/Shifts/73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6'
obj.shift.key == '73c81cc9-fa14-4fbe-9839-10c4121b3fc6'
```

If you want to load that reference you can use the reference `load` method directly:

```
obj.shift.load().then(shift => {
    shift.property = 'name';

    // Note that the obj.shift reference is resolved by the load call
    obj.shift === shift;

    return shift.save(); //do whatever you want to do with the reference
})
```

It is described in our guide in [object references](https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/crud/#object-references).

Another way to load the object with the referenced shift object directly is [deep loading](https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/deep-loading/#deep-loading) You can use deep loading to load an object with its references with one call:

```
// The depth: 1 parameter ensures that all directly referenced objects of obj
// will be resolved by the load call
DB.MyClassWithShiftReference.load(id, {depth: 1}).then(obj => {
    obj.shift.property = 'name';
})
```